# Finding death record of Charles Brown Filshie born 1910 Gorbals, Lanarkshire, Scotland?

Tags: 20th-century, death-records, scotland

He married Eliza Ward in Sunderland Durham England in 1936, but she remarried in 1944 stating she was widowed. However the Glasgow register of 1945 has Charles Brown Filshie living with his brother John and sister Margaret. No record of him after 1945.

I've looked for his death record on ScotlandsPeople and also in the UK death indexes, the CWGC register and deaths overseas. I've tried different spellings of the Filshie name, all returning negative results.

Comment: Do you know if the person you are looking for may still be alive? Not likely but there are 107 year olds out there so it's worth considering.

Comment: Very unlikely I'd say, but worth considering. However, I would have thought there would be mention of him after 1945 somewhere. He could have changed his name for some reason I guess. Is there a searchable register or index that anyone knows of?

Answer (score 1):

Ancestry.com has a record for a Charles Filshie in their All Canada, Voters Lists, 1935-1980.

In 1972 that Charles Filshie was a welder in Toronto, Ontario, Canada, and at the same address was a Hilda Filshie.

He may or may not be your Charles Brown Filshie but it is somewhere that you could broaden your search.  If you are unable to find evidence to support that he is your Charles Brown Filshie then be sure to also see if you can disprove whether Charles Brown, welder of Toronto, could be your Charles Brown Filshie.

Comment: This is a nephew of Charles Brown Filshie. He was living with his mother Hilda in the 1972 voters list. Hilda was married to James Taylor Filshie.  James Taylor Filshie and Charles Brown Filshie were brothers. Nice try but not who I'm looking for.